# How to get direct bitmap result using Blurry library

Tags: android, android-studio, blur, android-bitmap, blurry

Is there any way to get result as direct bitmap using the library blurry
https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry

```
Blurry.with(context).from(bitmap).into(imageView)
```

does  the blur but the output goes directly to the ImageView. Is there a way to get the bitmap result, so that I can later use it. Also while bluring The blur gets applied but givesthe following error

```
E/ANDR-PERF: IPerf::tryGetService failed!
```

I have already enabled renderscript

```
     renderscriptTargetApi 28
     renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [project's GitHub page](https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry), with the `Composer.async(ImageComposerListener listener)` you can attach an `ImageComposerListener` object, which will in turn get attached to the `BitmapComposer` object you get by calling `Blurry.from(Bitmap bitmap);`.
This listener defines a `void onImageReady(BitmapDrawable drawable);` function which will get invoked when calling `BitmapComposer.into(ImageView target)`. You can override and access the blurred bitmap by calling `drawable.getBitmap()`.

Note, I can't try this right now but it seems to be the solution for your question.